# Wordpress tinyMCE edit link dialog not working

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I have a problem regarding Wordpress/tinyMCE. 
Wordpress is 4.5.2 version, and is managed by hosting, so I can not edit tinyMCE files or replace it with different version but default one. 
The problem appears in front end only, while it workt normally in admin part of the WP.
When I click on "insert link" button in the toolbar, no dialog appears, and selected text gets the "a" tag, with href pointing to "_wp_link_placeholder".
TinyMCE is initialized using wp_editor() function from the PHP code.

Thanks in advance!